# jade нет вложености

Tags: jade

почему нет вложености? Не могу понять в чем проблема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
-   var currentProject = [['composition-project','Состав проекта'],
                         ['room', 'Помещения'],['terms', 'Скроки']];
UL.sidebar&attributes(attributes)
    LI(class= currentProject[0][0]) #{currentProject[0][1]}
    block
-       for (var i = 0; i < currentProject.length; i++) {
        LI(class= currentProject[i][0]) #{currentProject[i][1]}
-       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` сместите на `tab`

```
-   var currentProject = [['composition-project','Состав проекта'],
                         ['room', 'Помещения'],['terms', 'Скроки']];

UL.sidebar&attributes(attributes)
    block
    -   for (var i = 0; i < currentProject.length; i++) {
        LI(class= currentProject[i][0]) #{currentProject[i][1]}
    -   }
```

[Пример на codepen](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/jrPykg?editors=1100)

**Вариант без скобок** (обратите внимание на уровни, соблюдайте отступы):

```
-  var currentProject = [['composition-project','Состав проекта'], ['room', 'Помещения'],['terms', 'Скроки']];
ul.sidebar&attributes(attributes)
  -  for (var i = 0; i < currentProject.length; i++)
    li(class= currentProject[i][0]) #{currentProject[i][1]}
```

> В Jade нет закрывающих тегов. Вместо этого Jade использует табуляцию
>   для определения вложености тегов.

[Документация по jade. Ru](http://jsman.ru/jade/)

[Документация по pug. Eng](https://github.com/pugjs/pug)

Comment: сместил, тоже самое. Я обновил картинки, посмотрите

Comment: а тире(дефис) Вы кому оставили на месте?! ) Сравните свой скрин и мой ответ)

Comment: Это работает! Спасибо. Но IDE выдает ошибку и указывает на нижний брекет. Пишет "missing }" Очень странно

Comment: @HelpaMnePlz, потому что лучше будет вообще без скобок. Сейчас добавлю вариант.

Comment: @HelpaMnePlz, и вообще почитайте оф. документацию для jade, а еще лучше уже для pug

Comment: спасибо 2 вариант работает